# Select a column with an if expression

Tags: sql-server, select, grafana

For Grafana I want to make a selection in SQL Server with an IF expression.
eg:

```
IF ExampleDb.foo>ExampleDb.bar
Select [foo] AS green;
ELSE
Select [foo] AS red;

[bar] AS bar

Where [...]
```

"green"/"red" shouldn't be returned if the expression isn't true.
Is this possible to do?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve with your query? I don't think there is much sense in dynamically changing the name of the header. Maybe you want something like this: `SELECT foo, bar, CASE WHEN ExampleDb.foo>ExampleDb.bar THEN N'green' ELSE N'red' END AS color FROM... WHERE...` or this: `SELECT foo, CASE WHEN ExampleDb.foo>ExampleDb.bar THEN bar ELSE NULL END AS green_bar, CASE WHEN ExampleDb.foo<=ExampleDb.bar THEN bar ELSE NULL END AS red_bar`...?

Comment: Thank you very much. the goal is to have dynamically headers. Grafana should only render headers that exist. If i return red=null and green=foo, 2 columns will be rendered. I only want one column to be rendered, wich I can then give then color based on the name. In Grafana there is no way to ignore null values.

Comment: And you can't render on a value in a single cell of the column? So the column (not the cell) will be red or green for all values in this column?

Comment: Unfortunately not dynamically. I can only color it based on a fixed number. therefor I need the comparison in SQL.